# Algorithm for sequence calculation

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I'm looking for a hint to an algorithm or pseudo code which helps me calculate sequences.
It's kind of permutations, but not exactly as it's not fixed length. 
The output sequence should look something like this:

```
A
B
C
D
AA
BA
CA
DA
AB
BB
CB
DB
AC
BC
CC
DC
AD
BD
CD
DD
AAA
BAA
CAA
DAA
...
```

Every character above represents actually an integer, which gets incremented from a minimum to a maximum.
I do not know the depth when I start, so just using multiple nested for loops won't work.

It's late here in Germany and I just can't wrap my head around this. Pretty sure that it can be done with for loops and recursion, but I have currently no clue on how to get started.

Any ideas?

EDIT: B-typo corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from the OP, here's a way to do the sequence without storing the list.

Use an odometer analogy.  This only requires keeping track of indices.  Each time the first member of the sequence cycles around, increment the one to the right.  If this is the first time that that member of the sequence has cycled around, then add a member to the sequence.

The increments will need to be cascaded.  This is the equivalent of going from 99,999 to 100,000 miles (the comma is the thousands marker).

If you have a thousand integers that you need to cycle through, then pretend you're looking at an odometer in base 1000 rather than base 10 as above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're taking all combinations of four distinct digits of length 1, 2, 3, etc., allowing repeats.

So start with length 1:  { A, B, C, D }

To get length 2, prepend A, B, C, D in turn to every member of length 1.  (16 elements)

To get length 3, prepend A, B, C, D in turn to every member of length 2.  (64 elements)

To get length 4, prepend A, B, C, D in turn to every member of length 3.  (256 elements)

And so on.

If you have more or fewer digits, the same method will work.  It gets a little trickier if you allow, say, A to equal B, but that doesn't look like what you're doing now.

Comment: Good idea, I just played with that, however there

Comment: It looks like your comment is not complete.

Comment: yeah, the 5 minute thing... I wanted to say: Good idea, I just played with that, however there's a catch: It's not digits, but actual numbers and a lot of them (testing from 0-1000 right now). I tried storing them in a List and it will result in an OutOfMemoryException pretty soon (after the third 'dimension'). I don't care if this run's for hours, but it has to run... Any ideas without saving the previous results?

Comment: I posted another answer that doesn't need storage of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence looks more like (A<sup>n-1</sup> X A<sup>T</sup>) where A is a matrices and A<sup>T</sup> is its transpose.

```
A= [A,B,C,D]
```

> *A<sup>T</sup> X A<sup>n-1</sup>* ∀ (n=0)
>
> sequence= A,B,C,D
>
> *A<sup>T</sup> X A<sup>n-1</sup>* ∀ (n=2)
>
> sequence= AA,BA,CA,DA,AB,BB,CB,DB,AC,BC,CC,DC,AD,BD,CD,DD

You can go for any matrix multiplication code like [this](http://programsplusplus.blogspot.in/2012/04/matrix-multiplication-in-c.html) and implement what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 elements, you are simply looping the numbers in a reversed base 4 notation. Say A=0,B=1,C=2,D=3 :
first loop from 0 to 3 on 1 digit
second loop from 00 to 33 on 2 digits
and so on

```
i    reversed i    output using A,B,C,D digits
loop on 1 digit
0    0             A
1    1             B
2    2             C
3    3             D

loop on 2 digits
00   00            AA
01   10            BA
02   20            CA
03   30            DA
10   01            AB
11   11            BB
12   21            CB
13   31            DB
20   02            AC
21   12            BC
22   22            CC
...
```

The algorithm is pretty obvious. You could take a look at algorithm L (lexicographic t-combination generation) in [fascicle 3a TAOCP D. Knuth](http://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc3a.pdf).

Comment: yes, but i do not know how many elements i will actually have. This is determined in the process

Comment: If you do not know how many elements you'll have then you'll have to keep a list before the output ... one list per string size you'll have to complete each time you discover a new element ...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
  Private Sub DoIt(minVal As Integer, maxVal As Integer, maxDepth As Integer)
    If maxVal < minVal OrElse maxDepth <= 0 Then
      Debug.WriteLine("no results!")
      Return
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine("results:")

    Dim resultList As New List(Of Integer)(maxDepth)

    ' initialize with the 1st result: this makes processing the remainder easy to write.
    resultList.Add(minVal)
    Dim depthIndex As Integer = 0
    Debug.WriteLine(CStr(minVal))

    Do

      ' find the term to be increased
      Dim indexOfTermToIncrease As Integer = 0
      While resultList(indexOfTermToIncrease) = maxVal

        resultList(indexOfTermToIncrease) = minVal

        indexOfTermToIncrease += 1
        If indexOfTermToIncrease > depthIndex Then
          depthIndex += 1
          If depthIndex = maxDepth Then
            Return
          End If
          resultList.Add(minVal - 1)
          Exit While
        End If
      End While

      ' increase the term that was identified
      resultList(indexOfTermToIncrease) += 1

      ' output
      For d As Integer = 0 To depthIndex
        Debug.Write(CStr(resultList(d)) + " ")
      Next
      Debug.WriteLine("")

    Loop

  End Sub
```

Would that be adequate? it doesn't take much memory and is relatively fast (apart from the writing to output...).